# redirecting-to/adding www in url codeigniter based project

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am trying to add www and redirect all non-www urls to www urls in a codeigniter-based project, but my post data is not working after doing so. Here is the content of the Apache `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^examplesite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.examplesite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`.

Everything works like a charm if I do not have www urls. I have tried `REQUEST_URI`, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because browsers wont resubmit POST data if the response is a redirect. This is a normal and expected thing. What you can do is to only rewrite GET requests with an extra condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^examplesite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.examplesite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Leave the `$config['site_url']` option in `application/config/config.php` to an empty string (that will make CI do autodetect) and in your view code, use the [`site_url()`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) helper or the [form builder functions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) so it will use the domain that the request came in.

Comment: I understand what are you saying but I never found this solution "only rewrite GET requests" anywhere, strange that I only had such issue while forcing www to url. it should be a common issue and there should be references to this.

Comment: My guess would be that is POST requests are mostly generated from your own application (maybe you are running a service), and that should very much be aware of the fact that it should create posts to `www` domains, while GET requests can come from many source like search engines, bookmarks... however if you can't change your forms for some reason this at least make your code work.