# Can i use base_url with www in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have always seen the base_url as `http://example.com` in codeigniter having `http` and not `www`.

But I want to forcefully add `www` in my all urls, so shall I better use base_url as `www.example.com` ? will it create any issues at application level?

Comment: i would just use HTACCESS to rewrite the url with WWW. just incase someone trys to goto the non www version

Comment: @Dave I also thought the same earlier, but my post requests will have urls such as http://example.com/getmesomedata and while redirecting all non www urls to www, my post requests stops working. I had this issue earlier. look at it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303964/redirecting-to-adding-www-in-url-codeigniter-based-project

Comment: No, it will no create that problem. You need to be on the form's page to be able to submit the form and when you enter the form's page, it will redirect you to www. So, the form will always be with www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't create the problem when you define your `base_url='www.example.com'` but make sure your each link will contain `www` or forcefully redirected to www you can take care of `www`
redirection with `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: I basically wants to add www to all non www urls. is having a base-url with www along with htaccess is the correct approach for this?

Comment: yes it is a correct approach if you have any confusion then search around the internet about codeigniter with www redirection